# How can you copy/transfer my personal repository to the repository of the assignment

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have a project with it's own repository on my account. However I need to move the project to the repository of the assignment I accepted. I'm not experienced with github and I'm totally lost.

Current URL repository I'm working on:
https://github.com/MYUSERNAME/MYPROJECTNAME

The contents and everything below
[image]
should be moved to the repository of the assignment:
https://github.com/ORGANISATIONNAME/ASSIGNMENTNAME-MYUSERNAME

Comment: add the second repository as a `remote` to your local repo and then push the branch you need there. Check `git help remote`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+push+two+repositories